# I moved Oracle Instant Client, but it didn't actually move?

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis

I set up our local intranet on IIS running on a Windows Server 2012 using Oracle Instant Client to connect to our database.

I installed Oracle Instant Client to C:\instantclient during set up. It works and has done for 12 months.

For the sake of keeping C:\ tidy I copied the folder to C:\Program Files (x86)\instantclient and changed the path in PATH.

Here is where it gets strange:

I restarted the server to test, opened our local intranet so I knew that Oracle Instant Client would be in use, and tried deleting the original folder at C:\instantclient but I was told that it's in use.

I deleted the folder at C:\Program Files (x86)\instantclient and the local intranet continues to work. It's clearly using the original folder at C:\instantclient, but why?

As I mentioned, I updated PATH and restarted. There is literally no mention of C:\instantclient on this server, except the folder itself being there.

Why is it continuing to use the original folder?

Comment: What components of Instant Client did you install? Just the basic package, or ODBC/OLEDB as well?

Comment: @misha256 Basic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure every reference to `C:\instantclient` is identified and changed to the new location.

PATH is just one variable.  Look for `TNS_ADMIN` and others.

Then there's the Windows Registry. Some components of Instant Client (like the ODBC or OLEDB component) have entries in the Windows Registry. These components should always be installed/uninstalled via the supplied `exe` or `bat` scripts.

Are you using any other plugins, extensions, or components that may have their own configuration data still pointing to `C:\instantclient`?

I think this is also a good lesson in not trying to fix something that isn't broken. The server doesn't care whether `C:\` looks tidy, nor do end users.

Comment: `TNS_ADMIN` is for Linux. The only installation required is downloading it and adding it to `PATH` as per the Oracle website.

Comment: @user4499154 TNS_ADMIN can be and is used in Windows: http://www.omnicognic.com/Support/4/Oracle_Install_04.png

Comment: @user4499154 You're right, a *basic* InstantClient install only requires PATH to be set. So the only remaining logical explanation is that some other component/app/tool/utility/etc. running on your server has its own configuration pointing to `C:\instantclient`. At this point I suggest using *Resource Monitor* (comes with Windows) to determine what process or service has handles open against `C:\instantclient` and/or DLLs within that folder.